# How to add specfic elements to to HTML containers using DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm doing the Odin Project and am stuck on an exercise.

The requirement is that I have to add specific elements to a container in the HTML file but I can't get the following sections to show up at all when I run it:

a `<div>` with a black border and pink background color with the following elements inside of it:

another `<h1>` that says “I’m in a div”
a `<p>` that says “ME TOO!”

Hint for this one: after creating the `<div>` with createElement, append the `<h1>` and `<p>` to it before adding it to the container.

Here's my code https://codepen.io/mohd057/pen/KKQWdYV

```
const container = document.querySelector('#container');

const myP = document.createElement("p");
myP.style.color = "red"; 
myP.textContent = "Hey I'm red!"; 

const myH = document.createElement("h3")
myH.style.color = "blue"; 
myH.textContent = "I'm a blue h3!"; 

container.appendChild(myP);

container.appendChild(myH);

const myDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
myDiv.setAttribute('style', 'border: black; background: pink;'); 

    const anotherH = document.createElement("h1"); 
    anotherH.textContent = "I'm in a div"; 
    const anotherP = document.createElement("p"); 
    anotherP.textContent = "ME TOO!"; 

    container.appendChild(myDiv);
```

Here's the link to the exercise https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/foundations-dom-manipulation-and-events (struggling on questions 3, 1, and 2 are fine)

Would love to know where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is missing:

- `border` needs a [border-style](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp) property to show
- background's color property is called `background-color` otherwise you have to define it like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background_shorthand.asp)
- You didn't append any element inside `myDiv`

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container');

const myP = document.createElement("p");
myP.style.color = "red"; 
myP.textContent = "Hey I'm red!"; 

const myH = document.createElement("h3")
myH.style.color = "blue"; 
myH.textContent = "I'm a blue h3!"; 

container.appendChild(myP);

container.appendChild(myH);

const myDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
myDiv.setAttribute('style', 'border: black solid; background-color: pink;'); 

    const anotherH = document.createElement("h1"); 
    anotherH.textContent = "I'm in a div"; 
    const anotherP = document.createElement("p"); 
    anotherP.textContent = "ME TOO!"; 

    myDiv.appendChild(anotherH);
    myDiv.appendChild(anotherP);
    container.appendChild(myDiv);
```

Comment: This is working, but it would be nice if you'd give an additional explanation about what you have changed!

Comment: @aca Yes you're right, let me know if you have any other doubts